# Print function to an output file

Tags: c++, output

I am about to be finished with a program I am writing and have reached a roadblock.
I am trying to print the contents of a function called print which is called by a pointer.

My problem is I need to print the contents of the function to an output file and am not sure how.

This is my print function:

```
void English::Print(){

    int formatlength = 38 - (static_cast<int>(firstName.size() + lastName.size()));

    cout << firstName << " " << lastName;
    cout << setw(formatlength) << finalExam;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(11) << FinalGrade();
    cout << setw(4) << Lettergrade() << endl;
}
```

This is the implementation of the print function:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numStudents - 1; i++) {
    if (list[i]->GetSubject() == "English") {
        list[i]->Print();
    }
}
```

Where the for loop is cycling through my list of Students.

My goal is that the `list[i]->Print()` will print to my output file.

Comment: Revise the function to take an ostream reference as an argument (use `cout` as a default, perhaps) and pass it the relevant ostream for the output file when you want it to write to file instead of `cout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply replace `cout` with an `ostream` object, something like :

```
void English::Print(ostream& fout){
  //ofstream of("myfile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
  int formatlength = 38 - (static_cast<int>(firstName.size() + lastName.size()));

  fout << firstName << " " << lastName;
  fout << setw(formatlength) << finalExam;
  fout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(11) << FinalGrade();
  fout << setw(4) << Lettergrade() << endl;
}
```

Also, you can overload `<<` operator too in your class `English`

```
friend ostream& operator <<( ostream& os, const English& E )
{
  //
  return os;
}
```

And then can simply use:

`fout << list[i] ;`

Comment: I took your advice but 3 other problems arose. This is a project using derived classes and when I enter those parameters for my Print() function, then my child classes (English, Math, and History) all get an error for allocating an object of an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answers above, I think you should try this way, using the C's original file redirection function:

Put this instruction in the first line of your main function:

```
int main(){
    freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
    //your codes
```

The "out.txt" is the file you wanna to put the data in, "w" means you want to write in the file, and stdout is the standard output stream that has been redirected.